# mongo: java Command fails due to authorization

Tags: java, mongodb, connection, authorization

I have a weird problem here and want to know if someone has seen this before.

Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on db_vinylxl to execute command...'

This obviously indicates that the command is not allowed by the connected user. However, I use the same connection string with many other java programs. Without any problem.

Also I tried using it in the shell:

```
mongo mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/databasename
```

And I can do all the commands (such as updates) from that very shell.
I won't pull my hair out, because I haven't got much left.

Need to solve it somehow.
If any of you has seen this before or know what I could try, your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
mongo -u usaname -p password 127.0.0.1:27017/databasename
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual it was my own dumn fault.

I got a handle to a collection (static!) before being authenticated.
Changing the order fixed all problems.